# Flyway to execute some scripts before migrations to provide some sprocs in my schema

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have an in-house lib with all the sprocs to create some audit table and triggers for the tables that I would be adding in future as migration scripts  and I want these sprocs to be deployed to my schema before any of the migrations runs. I have a specific DDL that does it. The reason I want it that way is whenever I have a new table that I need to add, I can call this sproc to create those triggers and audit tables. That way my migration scripts would be cleaner and simpler.Also, this would help in keeping the H SQL and oracle scripts as much in sync as possible as I would not care about having audit or triggers for H SQL while doing dev work.

I have extracted from the library into a folder the DLL running the sprocs and it is in a separate folder as I want to have them separate to my migration scripts.

I don't have a Flyway bean created because spring boot did it for me. I don't see any properties configuration to create callbacks.

I am using spring boot 1.3.3-RELEASE and prefer to use flyway 3.2.1 which comes with spring boot parent dependencies.

Could someone suggest the best way to do this?

If there is a higher version of flyway supporting this, would you recommend override we specific version of flyway provided by spring boot with the new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:

Use [callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks). Flyway version 3.x has support for these which was improved upon in version 4. This includes hooks for `beforeMigrate`, `beforeEachMigrate` and `beforeBaseline` which is what you are after.

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Add the named SQL files (eg beforeMigrate.sql, beforeEachMigrate.sql) to the migrations directory.
2. Configure your callback Java classes with the [`callbacks`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate) property.
3. spring-boot offers [`FlywayMigrationStrategy`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayMigrationStrategy.java) to hook into the lifecycle and get access to the `Flyway` object. See the [spring-boot Flyway documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup).

Option 2.

Add those stored procedures to `V__1` so they are callable from each subsequent migration. Means you will have to forgo your desire of having them separated from the migrations of course - but much simpler.

Comment: @Component
public class FlywayCallbackService implements FlywayCallback {

}@Component
public class FlywayFactory implements FlywayMigrationStrategy {


    public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
        flyway.setCallbacks(new FlywayCallbackService());
        flyway.migrate();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Component 
public class FlywayFactory implements FlywayMigrationStrategy {      

@Override     
public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {         
flyway.setCallbacks(new FlywayCallbackService());         
flyway.migrate();     
}
 }
```

This did the work. thanks for the answer @markdsievers